# Can't see test output results in Eclipse

Tags: testng

I am unable to look at Test Results though i mentioned test-output directory in TestNG in Build Path -> Configure Build path -> TestNG -> Output Directory as test-output.

[image: Results]

Please help
Durga

Comment: I deliberately removed url and package name as don't want to disclose

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "_unable to look_"? The IDE already presents the results in its own view on the right, so it must be something else you're looking for like files? If that's so, try using the `Navigator` view because, if i remember correctly, the `Package Explorer` view displays only certain files.

Comment: just refresh the entire project after running tests. By clicking on the project folder.

Comment: Thank you @jithinkmatthew for the help. it works

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can click on "Open TestNG report" icon in Results of running suite tab. Refer attached screenshot and test-output folder will be visible. [image]